# Calling a new StartActivityForResult from onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to call a new Intent from within an "onActivityResult" function, but the results are not what I hoped for. It either loops endlessly, or quits early.

Within the "main" activity I create an array of bundles, then for each bundle I create an intent, wait for the current activity to return "done", then start a new one with the next bundle.

The problem is that the "main" activity restarts after every call to onActivityResult, which means it's onStart gets called again, and all my bundles are recreated in an endless loop. The only way to avoid this appears to be by adding "finish();" to the end of the onActivityResult function, but this stops the entire process after only one call to onActivityResult.

Here's the code (abridged):

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

   ArrayList<Bundle> bundles;
   int taskId = 0;
   // A few other things here; nothing important to this question.

    public void onCreate(savedInstanceState)) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bundles = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
    }

    public void onStart() {
        // Here I perform a loop that creates a number of bundles
        // and adds them to the "bundles" array (not shown).

        // Start the first activity:
        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, StuffDoer.class);
        firstIntent.putExtras(bundles.get(0));
        startActivityForResult(firstIntent, taskId);
        bundles.remove(0);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int result, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, result, data);
        if (result == RESULT_OK) {
            if (bundles.size() > 0) {
                taskId += 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, StuffDoer.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundles.get(0));
                startActivityForResult(intent, taskId);
                bundles.remove(0);
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "No more to do, finishing");
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Did not get the expected return code");
        }
        // finish(); // If I uncomment this, it only performs this function 
                     // once before quitting. Commented out, it loops forever 
                     // (runs the onStart, adds more bundles, etc.).
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you changing the layout orientation in those activities.. i.e portrait in calling activity landscape in receiving activity

Comment: @Vino, I don't think that changing the orientation in a activity is also destroying the calling activities.
natedc, did you try to move the iteration code to `onCreate`?

Comment: Moving the bundles creation loop to the onCreate function solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but if you only need to create your Bundles when the activity is first started, do it in onCreate(). Usually, the callbacks you implement for an activity are onCreate, onPause, and onResume. In an activity's normal life, it's in a lifecycle loop between onResume and onPause.

However, I'm curious. Why do you need to return to the main activity each time? It sounds as if your main activity "controls" the other activities. Usually, a better model for an Android app is to have each activity work independently, and switch to another activity when necessary. This is essentially a "program" with no "main", except for a "first among equals" activity that's started when the user clicks the app icon in the Launcher.

Comment: I was trying to serialize the execution of the second activity from the first; essentially using the "main" activity as a calling/sequencing activity. I think I'll just use it to create a bundles of bundles, then create a single intent. Then I can leave the handling of all the different iterations to the "stuffDoer" activity.

Comment: Moving the bundle creation loop to the onCreate function was the solution for the question I proposed, but your critique of my technique was spot on. I was calling activities as though they were just simple classes to instantiate, run, and then destroy. This is my first Android app, and my first ever "real world" program, so I'm definitely pushing my boundaries. Thanks for the help!